# New colour scheme makes it difficult to see the symbol of silver badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

Recently, a [new colour scheme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched?cb=1)  was introduced on Stack Exchange. In the new scheme, in Meta SO, the question asker’s profile has a grey background:
[image]

This grey background makes it difficult the spot the symbol of the silver badges as the colour of the silver badges is almost the same shade of grey. Can the colour of the background be made a lighter shade of grey?

Comment: The color of the user card is a bug. We've got it logged.